# Problema al mandar a generar un pdf

Tags: php, pdf

Hola buenas todos disculpen tengo un problema al momento de generar un pdf ya que me sale un error no se quien podria ayudarme

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
>       implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\simple-invoice-master\pdf_class
>       \locale.class.php on line 68
>
> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
>   implements   Countable in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\simple-invoice-master\pdf_class \locale.class.php on
>   line 68 TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF
>   file

Se los agradeceria mucho si alguien me podria dar alguna pista de lo que se trata a clarando la linea 68 que se muestra en el error es esta

```
     if (count($line)!=2) continue;
      self::$_list[trim($line[0])] = trim($line[1]);
       }
```

apartir del if es cuando comienza el problema,

Comment: ¿Qué contiene `$line`? ¿Cómo lo has creado? El problema subyacente está en el contenido de esa variable. Es posible que sea el resultado `"mixed"` devuelto por alguna función.

Answer (score 2):

Buenas yo lo solucioné añadiendo al inicio de la función load($code) (la funcion que contiene la lina 68 que comentas) lo siguiente:

```
ob_start();
```

y al final de la misma:

```
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 1):

Excelente, si funciono
Así tiene que quedar, por si hay dudas

```
ob_start();
    // load the file
    self::$_list = array();
    $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $line = fgetcsv($handle);
         if (count($line)!=2) continue; 
        self::$_list[trim($line[0])] = trim($line[1]);
    }
    ob_end_clean();
```